# How do I get user input to select a row in a two dimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I am trying to write a program that will take the sum of a selected row of a two dimensional array and show the sum, via user input to select the specific row. How do I go about doing this? I have tried to do it but I can't figure out how to do it without showing EVERY row.

My code:

```
int[,] array1 = new int[6, 6]
{
    {10, 20, 10, 20, 21, 99 },
    {2, 27, 5, 45, 20, 13 },
    {17, 20, 20, 33, 33, 20 },
    {21, 35, 15, 54, 20, 37 },
    {31, 101, 25, 55, 26, 66 },
    {45, 20, 44, 12, 55, 98 }
};

int Length = array1.GetLength(0);
int Height = array1.GetLength(1);
int CalculateRow = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < Length; i++ )
{
  for ( int j = 0; j < Height; j++ )
  {
    CalculateRow = CalculateRow + array1[i, j];
  }
  Console.Write("Enter the number of the Row you would like to see the sum of: ");
  int h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  if ( h > 5 )
  {
    Console.Write(-1);
  }
  else
    Console.WriteLine("The sum of Row {0} is {1} ", h, CalculateRow);
}
```

Comment: What is `Length`?

Comment: Can you explain what your code does differently than you want?

Comment: You won't have to iterate over both dimensions; the second dimension is the columns and you want to sum them. So, just get the array and sum it.

Comment: I am attempting to make it so the user inputs a number from 0 to 5 to select a specific row, and it will show the sum of the user's selected row. If it is not a valid row, it will show -1.

Comment: However, it is instead showing ALL row sums, while I want it to only show one.

Comment: You need to either encapsulate `CalculateRow = CalculateRow + array1[i, j];` into an if statement that will only run when the the row is the one the user entered. You can't do this because you ask for the row after the fact. You could either move that to before you calculate, or better yet make `CalculateRow` into a 1d array that is 5 rows, and then do `CalculateRow[i] += array[i,j]`

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this revised**

```
int[,] array1 = new int[6, 6]
{
  {10, 20, 10, 20, 21, 99 },
  {2, 27, 5, 45, 20, 13 },
  {17, 20, 20, 33, 33, 20 },
  {21, 35, 15, 54, 20, 37 },
  {31, 101, 25, 55, 26, 66 },
  {45, 20, 44, 12, 55, 98 }
};

int Length = array1.GetLength(0);
int Height = array1.GetLength(1);
int CalculateRow = 0;

Console.Write("Enter the number of the Row you would like to see the sum of: ");
int h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if ( h < 0 || h >= Length )
{
  Console.Write(-1);
}
else
{
  for ( int j = 0; j < Height; j++ )
  {
    CalculateRow = CalculateRow + array1[h, j];
  }
  Console.WriteLine("The sum of Row {0} is {1} ", h, CalculateRow);
}
```

We ask the user to input the row index before doing the loop on the items of the selected row to do the sum.

**You may refactor variables**

To have a more consistent and relevant naming to be more clean.

As well as use TryParse instead of Convert: it returns false if the input string can't be converted instead of an exception.

*For example*

```
int[,] matrix = new int[6, 6]
{
  {10, 20, 10, 20, 21, 99 },
  {2, 27, 5, 45, 20, 13 },
  {17, 20, 20, 33, 33, 20 },
  {21, 35, 15, 54, 20, 37 },
  {31, 101, 25, 55, 26, 66 },
  {45, 20, 44, 12, 55, 98 }
};

int rowsCount = matrix.GetLength(0);
int columnsCount = matrix.GetLength(1);
int rowSum = 0;

Console.Write("Enter the number of the Row you would like to see the sum of ");
Console.Write("(0 to " + (rowsCount - 1) + "): ");
if ( !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var rowIndex)
  || rowIndex < 0 
  || rowIndex >= rowsCount )
{
  Console.Write("Wrong index.");
}
else
{
  for ( int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnsCount; columnIndex++ )
  {
    rowSum = rowSum + matrix[rowIndex, columnIndex];
  }
  Console.WriteLine("The sum of Row {0} is {1} ", rowIndex, rowSum);
}
```

**To show the sum of each row**

```
for ( int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowsCount; rowIndex++ )
{
  rowSum = 0;  // reset the sum between rows
  for ( int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnsCount; columnIndex++ )
  {
    rowSum = rowSum + matrix[rowIndex, columnIndex];
  }
  Console.WriteLine("The sum of Row {0} is {1} ", rowIndex, rowSum);
}
```

*Result*

```
The sum of Row 0 is 180
The sum of Row 1 is 112
The sum of Row 2 is 143
The sum of Row 3 is 182
The sum of Row 4 is 304
The sum of Row 5 is 274
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
Console.Write("Enter the number of the Row you would like to see the sum of: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int h;
//validates the input more safely
if(int.TryParse(input, out h) && h >= 0 && h < 6)
{
    int sum = 0;
    //loop over only the row that you care about
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        sum += array1[h, i];

    Console.WriteLine("The sum of Row {0} is {1} ", h, sum);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a List of ints to hold the sum of each row, then return the row the user requests. Alternatively, ask the user which row they want *before* you calculate the sum, and only add the value `if(h == i)`

```
int[,] array1 = new int[6, 6]
{
    {10, 20, 10, 20, 21, 99 },
    {2, 27, 5, 45, 20, 13 },
    {17, 20, 20, 33, 33, 20 },
    {21, 35, 15, 54, 20, 37 },
    {31, 101, 25, 55, 26, 66 },
    {45, 20, 44, 12, 55, 98 }
};

int Length = array1.GetLength(0);
int Height = array1.GetLength(1);
List<int> CalculateRow = new List<int>(){0,0,0,0,0};

for ( int i = 0; i < Length; i++ )
{
  for ( int j = 0; j < Height; j++ )
  {
    CalculateRow[i] = CalculateRow + array1[i, j];
  }
  Console.Write("Enter the number of the Row you would like to see the sum of: ");
  int h = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  if ( h > 5 )
  {
    Console.Write(-1);
  }
  else
    Console.WriteLine("The sum of Row {0} is {1} ", h, CalculateRow[h]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to consider using a `List<int[]>` you can leverage Linq's `Sum` method and avoid the nested loops. here is a version of the code that does what you need.

```
    List<int[]> array1 = new List<int[]> { 
        new [] {10, 20, 10, 20 },
        new [] {3, 27, 5, 45 },
        new [] {17, 20, 20, 33 },
        new [] {21, 35, 15, 54 }
    };

    int input = 0;
    while(input < array1.Count)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the number of the Row you would like to see the sum of: ");
        input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (input > array1.Count)
            Console.Write(-1);          
        else
        {
            int total = array1.ElementAt(input - 1).Sum(i => i);
            Console.WriteLine("The sum of Row {0} is {1} ", input, total);
        }
    }
```

HTH